# How do i make a wordpress block that outputs html?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to make a wordpress (gutenberg) block  where you can input text. The output wil be the to be a expandable textfield from bootstrap. **https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/**

The wordpress documentation example did not work. 
So i used some php and javascript code from a tutorial to try make a wordpress block for the first time:

Functions.php

```
function mdlr_editable_block_example_backend_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'mdlr-editable-block-example-backend-script', // Unique handle.
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/block.js', // Block.js: We register the block here.
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor' ), // Dependencies, defined above.
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'block.js' ) // filemtime — Gets file modification time.
    );
```

block.js

```
/**
 * Editable Block Example
 *
 * https://github.com/modularwp/gutenberg-block-editable-example
 */
( function() {
    var __                = wp.i18n.__; // The __() function for internationalization.
    var createElement     = wp.element.createElement; // The wp.element.createElement() function to create elements.
    var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType; // The registerBlockType() function to register blocks.
    var RichText          = wp.editor.RichText; // For creating editable elements.

    /**
     * Register block
     *
     * @param  {string}   name     Block name.
     * @param  {Object}   settings Block settings.
     * @return {?WPBlock}          Block itself, if registered successfully,
     *                             otherwise "undefined".
     */
    registerBlockType(
        'mdlr/editable-block-example', // Block name. Must be string that contains a namespace prefix. Example: my-plugin/my-custom-block.
        {
            title: __( 'Editable Block Example' ), // Block title. __() function allows for internationalization.
            icon: 'unlock', // Block icon from Dashicons. https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/.
            category: 'common', // Block category. Group blocks together based on common traits E.g. common, formatting, layout widgets, embed.
            attributes: {
                content: {
                    type: 'string',
                    default: 'Editable block content...',
                },
            },

            // Defines the block within the editor.
            edit: function( props ) {
                var content = props.attributes.content;
                var focus = props.focus;

                function onChangeContent( updatedContent ) {
                    props.setAttributes( { content: updatedContent } );
                }

                return createElement(
                    RichText,
                    {
                        tagName: 'p',
                        className: props.className,
                        value: content,
                        onChange: onChangeContent,
                        focus: focus,
                        onFocus: props.setFocus
                    },
                );
            },

            // Defines the saved block.
            save: function( props ) {
                var content = props.attributes.content;

                return createElement( RichText.Content,
                    {
                        'tagName': 'div',
                        'value': content
                    }
                );
            },
        }
    );
})();
```

This code works.  The first test i did was changing the content:

```
save: function( props ) {
                var content = props.attributes.content;

                return '<div> test </div>';
            }
```

The i tried this:

```
save: function( props ) {
                var content = props.attributes.content;

                return <div> test </div>;
```

I seem to be missing or misinterpreting something.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can not return html element directly from your save or edit functions. Go to https://babeljs.io/repl, select 2015 and react and past the html markup into the box and transpile. You can have one root element, so whole thing should be wrapped in single htlm element. Check out react element, since return elements for save and edit should be valid react elements.